# Why landscape and Portrait returning same frame size?

Tags: objective-c, frame, allocation

I am printing views's frame value in ViewDidLoad.I portrait I am getting value as `frame rect is {{0, 20}, {768, 1004}}` and in Landscape I am getting as `frame rect is {{20, 0}, {748, 1024}}`.where as I know frames values get interchanged in portrait and landscape mode I mean width becomes height and vice-versa.Can anyone tell me what is the problem and how I can allocate frame to views to avoid orientation problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: i think you should tell us whats the problem with the above scenario.

Answer (score 0):

By default autoResizingMask is no set,so you are getting the same rect frames on portrait & landscape mode. Set the autoresingmask for the view and check the changes in the rect.

Comment: I have set autoResizingMask as  self.view.autoresizingMask=(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin);
.Is there any problem?

Comment: Fine but try to use only required keys. Did your problem solved?

Comment: No my problem is not yet solved.Which keys I need to provide?

Comment: Are you performing resizing in ipad.

Comment: From ipad you mean device?No I am using simulator.

Comment: Are you creating your application for iphone or ipad

Comment: If you have set the values of self.view.frame than values will change on orientation.suppose if you have set the hard coded values than it will not change. May be you have set the self.view.frame values so you are getting that result

Comment: No I have not set any values to self.view.frame.

Comment: conclusion to your problem. As I read the apple doc then I came to know that 20 frame are default allocated for status bar(time,battery indicator etc...). The frame what your getting is correct.